# Copy one file to one folder at a time where there are 100 files and 100 folders to copy using Batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have two folders `CopyFrom` and `CopyTo` where `CopyFrom` has 100 text files named as `1.txt`…`100.txt` and in `CopyTo` folder I have 100 folders as `F1`…`F100`. Now, I want to copy one file from `CopyFrom` folder to one folder in `CopyTo` so that `F1` will contain `1.txt`, `F2` will contain `2.txt`,…, `F100` will contain `100.txt` file.

I know to copy all folders I can use something like `For /d %%a in (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ShortCuts\*) do xcopy "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Time.xls" "%%a"`, but I could not find a way to copy different files to different folders.

I can echo all the files `(For %%a in (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ShortCuts\*) Echo "%%a")` in the `CopyFrom` folder and also can Echo all the folders in `CopyTo` folder but could not figure out to working with both to get what I am looking for.

Comment: You haven't made it clear if the destination folders are named the same as the source files or if you just want to place each individual source file into a different unknown named destination folder.

Comment: Do all the folders `F1`, `F2`, etc., in `CopyTo` location already exist? if not, do they have to be created?

Comment: @Compo, sorry about that, `CopyTo` folder has 100 folders (e.g F1, F2,...F100) and those folders name is not same as the source file being copied. When I said, **can be different**, I meant, destination folder name or the source files name can be different as I mentioned in the example.

Comment: @aschipfl, `F1, F2,...F100` folders are already exist..

Comment: I see. and file `27.txt` must be copied into folder `F27` (same numbers), right?

Comment: @aschipfl, yes, that is the intention at the moment..

Comment: @Viki the above response is in direct conflict with the response you gave me. Please ensure that we have the task parameters correct, is 4.txt supposed to go into F4 and 86.txt supposed to go into F86. (To worsen your clarity you also originally said 'preferably' first file to F1).

Comment: @Compo, I have edited the question as `1.txt should go in F1, 2.txt should go in F2....100.txt should be in F100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing the source location contains the files `1.txt` to `100.txt` only and the target location already contains all the `F1` to `F100` directories, the following code snippet might work for you:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "Pattern=*.txt"
set "CopyFrom=."
set "CopyTo=D:\Target"

for %%F in ("%CopyFrom%\%Pattern%") do (
    ECHO copy "%%~F" "%CopyTo%\F%%~nF\"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

There is no enumeration of the target location done, the copy destination is simply derived from the source file name.

**After having tested the script, remove the upper-case `ECHO` command to actually copy files!**

Comment: it would be great if you can explain this please `copy "%%~F" "%CopyTo%\F%%~nF\"`

Comment: This copies the each source file (`%%~F`) to the folder rooted at `%CopyTo%` and named `F`, followed by the base name of the current file (if the file is `27.txt`, `%%~nF` equals `27`; type `for /?` into a command prompt window and see the bottom of the help text); the final backslash ensures that the target it a folder, but not a file...

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configure paths
    set "copyFrom=c:\somewhere"
    set "copyTo=c:\anotherPlace"

    rem Generate two lists, one with files and one with folders
    dir /b /a-d "%copyFrom%\*" > "%temp%\copyFromFiles.txt"
    dir /b /ad  "%copyTo%\*"   > "%temp%\copyToFolders.txt"

    rem Assign each list as input to two streams and start processing    
    9< "%temp%\copyFromFiles.txt" 8< "%temp%\copyToFolders.txt" (
        call :matchFromWithTo
    )

    rem Remove generated lists
    del "%temp%\copyFromFiles.txt"
    del "%temp%\copyToFolders.txt"

    rem End
    goto :eof

:matchFromWithTo
    rem Read file from stream 9 and leave if nothing read
    <&9 set /p "file="   || goto :eof 
    rem Read folder from stream 8 and leave if nothing read
    <&8 set /p "folder=" || goto :eof

    rem Do the copy (debug: we will only echo the command)
    echo copy "%copyFrom%\%file%" "%copyTo%\%folder%"

    rem Keep reading until all files or folders are processed
    goto :matchFromWithTo
```

Comment: Good idea using input redirection! What about adding `/on` to the `dir` command lines in order to get sorted outputs (also on non-NTFS volumes)?

Comment: @aschipfl, Thank you. The *"... can be different ...."* made me discard the option. Without having a clear relation between files/folders names, I decided to simply iterate in file system default order.